# Can't get first td in tr with css3 selectors

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue selecting the first `td` in the `tr` on a table that is being created.

I am using

`.record_list tbody tr td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}`

and that does not work. No styles are being applied.

here is the html, im trying to get the `td` with the check mark.

```
<table class="records_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>✔</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Context</th>
                <th>Flagged</th>
                <th>Deferuntil</th>
                <th>Due</th>
                <th>Repeattask</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>✔</td>
                <td>This is another task title</td>
                <td>this is another note that will go with this task, just so nothing is forgotten.</td>
                <td>secondproject</td>
                <td>secontcontext</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2014-02-12 08:17:00</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/workspace/symfony/web/task/10">View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/workspace/symfony/web/task/10/edit">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                                <td></td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                                <td>this is a note that will describe anything that needs to be remembered about the note.</td>
                <td>thisisaproject</td>
                <td>thisisacontext</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/workspace/symfony/web/task/9">View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/workspace/symfony/web/task/9/edit">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the selector: `.record_list` should be `.records_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `.record_list` up there in your example but `.records_list` in your HTML. Is this what you're looking for?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LWevY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo records_list:

Change:

```
.record_list tbody tr td:first-child { text-align: center; }
```

With:

```
.records_list tbody tr td:first-child { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "s" to `.record_list` :)

```
.records_list tbody tr td:first-child{ background: red; }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JSrHD/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typed error `.record_list` instead `.records_list`